# Cancel a selection key but reuse it afterwards

Tags: java, select, nio

I want to register a channel to a selector at first to perform `select()` on connect only and afterwards on write only.

something like this:

```
SelectionKey key = server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
server.connect(address);
int readyChannels = 0;
while (readyChannels == 0) readyChannels = selector.select(config.connectTimeout);
server.finishConnect();
key.cancel();

key = server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
// write something to the channel and check timeout 
// with selector.select(config.writeTimeout)
```

However, when I reach the 2nd `register(...)` in the code I get a `CancelledKeyException`.

Is there some other way to do this?

Is the right way to do it is to define a new selector every time?

P.S. I know I can use `key.isWritable()` and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If `finishConnect()` returns false it isn't correct to proceed as though it had returned true.
2. Your problem is that you aren't calling the selector in between the cancel and the register, so there is unfinished business. The simplest solution here is to remove the cancel and the register and just adjust the interestOps of the existing selection key directly.
3. However as you are just effectively blocking until the connect completes, it would be simpler to do the connect *in* blocking mode, and go to non-blocking afterwards, for the subsequent I/O:

   ```
   // Still in blocking mode, no register() yet ...
   server.socket().connect(address, connectTimeout);
   server.configureBlocking(false);
   key = server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
   ```

   ... noting that if the timeout expires, an exception is thrown.

I've rarely encountered a case in which it makes any sense to use NIO in non-blocking mode at all in a client, actually.

Comment: Hmm... Isn't `selector.select(config.connectTimeout)` calling the selector?

Comment: I repeat. Your problem is that you aren't calling the selector in between the cancel and the register.

Comment: Ha. I was looking at the first register rather than the second. Didn't occur to me you might need to call the selector *after* the cancel... Anyway thanks, I'll try it first thing on Sunday.

Comment: Upvoted and added a suggested revised code according to your comments, is that more or less what you meant?

Comment: No. Your suggested edit didn't take into account my point 1. What I'm really suggesting is my point 3. There's no sense in doing it the way you're doing it in your question.

Comment: How about `if (selector.select(config.connectTimeout) == 0 || !key.isConnectable()) { ... }`?

Comment: **Why?** `connect()` has a timeout parameter. Do you have some objection to doing things the easy way?

Comment: Don't get upset... so you mean that I would do the connect directly on the socket? Like `server.socket().connect(address, config.connectTimeout);`?

Comment: Not upset, just baffled why you insist on doing everything the hard way.

Comment: I'm really don't, I just didn't remember there was a connect with timeout. As to your remark regarding using nio - the sole reason I need it in this case is because I need timeout on writes too. Anyway, thanks a lot for the time you invested in this, appreciated!